# Receive-Job different than direct call

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Needed to change my code from direct call to Start-Job precedure because of timeouts caused by Symantec Antivirus (SEP) v14, making my script hanging.

this snap was working fine so long:

```
$updateDaten = Get-HotFix -computername "myserver" | % { $_.psbase.properties["installedOn"].Value } | Group-Object | select-object Name
```

The change to a start-job preocedure completely messes up the resulting object. im googling and testing for two days now but cannot find out what's so complicatet in dealing with job objects:

```
function Get-HotfixesListAsJob($computer, $timeout){
  $job = Start-Job { param($c) Get-HotFix -computername $c | 
                     % { $_.psbase.properties["installedOn"].Value } | Group-Object
                   } -ArgumentList $computer

  Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeout
  Stop-Job $job 
  Receive-Job $job 
  Remove-Job $job

}


$updateDaten = Get-HotfixesListAsJob -computer "myserver" -timeout 80
```

However I am not able to get the same result back using Receive-Job. I Always get some wired job-object and I am not able to just extract the data as it was before.  Why is the result so completely different? is it possible to get just the data back in an object as it was before instead of a job object?

btw. this interesting article did not solve my problem:
https://learn-powershell.net/2014/06/27/quick-hits-did-i-really-lose-my-output-with-receive-job-by-not-usingkeep/

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: Your code works. Firstly in the function you don't `select-object Name` so you get other properties as well - RunspaceId, Group, etc. Secondly, the otuput of `wait-job` is output by your function too, and you probably want `Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeout | Out-Null` to silence it. But the results of Get-HotFix are returned from your function...

Comment: Thank you @TessellatingHeckler `Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeout | Out-Null` really solved the problem! The output was messed up the returning object, I did never consider this behaviuor. Unfortunately it is not commonly documented and dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

The issue what you are having is not because of the code. Its because Start-job or any PS Job session, basically, will have all the details, properties related to that job.

So, I can see in the first case you have done a grouping and finally selecting only the *name* which is not there in the later case.

So I would suggest you to add that to the Function also.

One more thing , *Wait-job* will also output the value in the console. Either redirect or pipe it to null in order to avoid that.

You can also receive the job using *receive-job* with the job id or the name. I think that will be better. Just check the status of the job; Once done receive it.

Comment: thanks! `Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeout | Out-Null` solved my object-mess! After grouping I have the attributes `Count, Name, Group` in my object. So i consider to use only the distinct values of `Name`.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer from  TessellatingHeckler. I noticed it later. He has stated more precisely. :)